# spark reduceByKey() not shuffling for the final sum

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have an RDD containing the count for some objects and then I apply reduceByKey() on it, summing up all the elements (like in the word count example). I've saved the output of the reduceByKey transformation to a text file and I have the sum for each of the workers:

```
(work at  LEFT null,9741)
(work at  LEFT null,10073)
(work at  LEFT null,10348)
(work at  LEFT null,10483)
(work at  LEFT null,10754)
```

Shouldn't it be only one item, which would be the sum of them all ?

If more detail is needed, I will provide it.

LE: the object I am trying to count is defined by

```
public class Pattern {
     string pattern;
     PatternType type;
     Relation r;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of your key? Show us your transformations.

Comment: It's a custom class I created. I'm pretty sure that the objects are the same.

Comment: Is it a case class? How is it defined?

Comment: You're using Java?

Comment: Yeah :) figured it wouldn't matter

Comment: It really metters indeed since case classes have auto-generated `hasCode` and `equals` based on fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark, `PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey` takes the `RDD[(K, V)]` and partitions the data (causing a shuffle) using the defined partitioner. If no such partitioner is provided, it uses the default `HashPartitioner` to decide which key value pair gets passed to which worker. If you're using a Java class as your key which doesn't override it's `hashCode` method, `reduceByKey` will decide how to partition the data based on Java's `Object.hashCode`. This means that identical keys will be offloaded to different workers where they will be partially reduced together. Ideally, that isn't what you want. What you want is that all objects with the same key will get reduced via the same worker. Then, when they will be shuffled after each worker reduces it's own, the combiner for all keys won't be able to match the keys based on their hash code, which explains why you're seeing only partially reduced data instead of the summed up data on a single key.

What you need to do is provide a proper `hashCode` **and** `equals` implementation. This is stated in the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs) (thanks @VitaliyKotlyarenko):

> **Note:** when using custom objects as the key in key-value pair operations, you must be sure that a custom equals() method is accompanied with a matching hashCode() method. For full details, see the contract outlined in the Object.hashCode() documentation

For example:

```
public class Pattern {
     string pattern;
     PatternType type;
     Relation r;

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
        return 371 * pattern.hashCode();
     }

     @Override 
     public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null || this.getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;

        Pattern pattern = (Pattern) other;
        return this.pattern.equals(pattern.pattern);
     }
}
```

Comment: I must add that this is not only common, but required to provide `equals` with `hashCode`. Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs) is clear about that: "when using custom objects as the key in key-value pair operations, you must be sure that a custom equals() method is accompanied with a matching hashCode() method."

Comment: Note that you can design your `hashCode()` to actually avoid shuffling between stages. However in that case it is probably more desirable to customize your partitioner instead to avoid other side effects.

Comment: @YoYo Does he need to do any more then make sure two equal objects have the same hash?

Comment: You also would want to take other design considerations into account when designing the `hashCode()`, or a custom partitioner for that matter. One thing is if you plan on distributing tasks to nodes or workers, you do not want one worker ending up with most of the work causing tasks to be queued up, while the other has almost nothing to work on. This is a pretty common concept with distributed computing.

Comment: @YoYo You're talking about skewing the keys?

Comment: Skew, exactly. Didn't have a name for it till just now, but that was how we named it for Teradata as well in regards to AMP distribution.